# Display Bitmap Image from Access to Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, ms-access

Regards for all Delphi Guru :)

I have table in Access 2010, one of the column type is OLE Object named "ProductImage"
I use that column to save Bitmap Image.

The problems is, How can I display that image using DBImage or TImage in Delphi 7?
I've tried this

`procedure TF_Search2.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
 Image7.Picture.Assign(DataModule1.T_Products.FieldByName('ProductImage').LoadFromFile('c:\test.jpg'));
  end;`

It's error : need parameter in this part 'LoadFromFile('c:\test.jpg')'
I tried also using "TBlobField", but I got error : undeclared identifier TBlobField
I read that it should in unit and uses. I don't understand what's that mean.
Should I add something on installation folder or what?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is never enough. In what way does it fail? Error messages and so on.

Comment: Hi @david, thanks for your reply.
Yes, It's error : need parameter in this part 'LoadFromFile('c:\test.jpg')'

Is there any way beside that code?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the missing details.

Answer (score 2):

The field also contains an OLE Header. I ancient times I skipped this (I think the first 79 bytes) but I cannot find the code anymore. However, the internet has solutions as always. Imho this one is better than my 'skip' solution.

Here is one of them:[How to read and write images from/to an access DB (page 4)](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa030601a.htm)

EDIT: I just saw that your problem is your syntax.

```
procedure TF_Search2.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn); 
begin 
  Image7.Picture.Assign(DataModule1.T_Products.FieldByName('ProductImage').LoadFromFile('c:\test.jpg')); 
end;
```

This is not valid delphi syntax and quite confusing. The `Picture.Assign` method expects a picture object. So what you first would want to do is to get the picture out of the access-DB.

You want to read the image data from an access db and display it in an image component?

Follow the steps in the link.

EDIT: I did find some very old code which I modified (and cannot test):

```
 aBitmapStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

 tblDrawing_BitmapColumnBLobField.SaveToStream (aBitmapStream);

 // This hack enables Access BMP-Blobs to be imported 
 aBitmapStream.Seek (78,soFromBeginning);
 myBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
 myBitmap.LoadFromStream (aBitmapStream);

 Image7.Picture.Assign (myBitmap);

 myBitmap.Free;
 aBitmapStream.Free;
```

Comment: Hi @alzamair, 
Thank you for the link.
I'll try that and get back to you with the result

Comment: I got error on this part :
' function JpegStartsInBlob (PicField:TBlobField):integer;
var
 bS     : TADOBlobStream;
 buffer : Word;
 hx     : string;'

Error : undeclared identifier TBlobField, undeclared identifier TADOBlobStream
Why is that?

Comment: Btw, It worked few minutes ago. After I add new data on access, It error "Bitmap is not valid!"
I tries bmp, jpeg is not working.
What type of image that I should save in access btw?

Comment: You can save (and open) all type of images you support by your application. For JPG you have to use TJpegImage, for PNG you have to use TPngImage and for BMP you have to use TBitmap, etc. So you also have to store the kind of image or test with all supported types trial-error

Comment: Hi @SirRufo, I saved the image on access in .bmp but still has the same error.
Do you how I can use TBlogField? It keeps appear undeclared identifier on my end.

Comment: @user Your question was answered. Don't ask us to debug your entire program. If you don't know what to do when you encounter "undeclared identifier" errors, you need more fundamental help.